# Why am I getting an empty body response for user feedback in sentry?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sentry, raven

I am using ReactJS to set up the user feedback for Sentry.

I initialize it with:

```
import Raven from 'raven-js';

Raven.config(https://#########@sentry.io/#######, {
  environment: "development",
}).install();
```

And used the componentDidCatch in ErrorBoundary(https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) concept to show the report dialog.

```
componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
    Raven.captureException(error, { extra: info });
    Raven.showReportDialog();
}
```

When I submit the dialog, the network shows me a POST request with a 200 Response and a confirmation dialog that it was successful. However, the body is empty and the submitted form can't be seen in the user feedback section of my project on my sentry account.

The behavior looks as seen on this site: https://wiggly-power.glitch.me/

Comment: Still bumping into this two years later. It's a strange issue, because it was working just the other day. I could have sworn I had to enable some option to do this last time. I'll try to follow up if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should only call function componentDidCatch(..), setState(..) and so on to check in this situation. Don't try to do the business flow in this function.

```
componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
    Raven.captureException(error, { extra: info });
}
```

Look at [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidcatch) and try call these function in render() method:

```
if (this.state.hasError) {
 Raven.showReportDialog();
}
```

Comment: Nope. This did not and won't work. The dialog is already owned by Sentry. And, placement would not matter. I just followed the docs as stated here. https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/usage/#javascript-user-feedback